# When I submit a form on Laravel I get error message: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219?

Tags: forms, laravel

When I submit my form I receive the following error: 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219'.

How do I solve this? I have looked at various forums and other threads where this has been answered but none have worked for me.

My route file is as follows:

```
<?php
/*
This is the file in which the rules for how users will use the application are kept
*/

Route::get('/',function() {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('/questionnaires', 'QuestionnairesController');

Route::resource('/questions', 'QuestionsController');

Route::resource('/answers', 'AnswersController');
```

\

My create.blade.php file along with the form looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Create Questionnaire | SurveySays!')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h1>Create Questionnaire</h1>
        <h3>Create your questionnaire using the form below. Give it a title, a small description and write your ethical considerations:</h3>

        @if($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif

        {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/questionnaires/create')) !!}

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('title',null,['id' => 'title','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('description',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('ethics', 'Ethical considerations:') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('ethics',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Create', array('class' => 'btn btn-success form-control')) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `store` method instead. Also, use route, not URL (you don't want to hardcode it):

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'questionnaires.store') !!}
```

`create` method is used to display form to a user. And `store` used to validate and persist user input data into DB.

More about [RESTful resource controllers here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Comment: I changed to this and submitted form again and I receive this error now SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `questionnaires` (`title`, `description`, `ethics`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Title, Description, Ethical, 2016-04-30 14:33:59, 2016-04-30 14:33:59))

Comment: Also my database table is empty even when I have submitted forms

Comment: Table is empty, because you're getting the error I guess. You get the error, because you've created migration without timestamps. Now, you should recreate this table or if you don't need timestamps, add this to your model: `public $timestamps = false;` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: I have timestamps in my migration though?
            $table->timestamp('start_date');
            $table->timestamp('end_date');

Comment: Look at your error message above. Laravel can't find `updated_at`. You should add `$table->timestamps();` to migration, roll it back and migrate again. https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#migration-structure - Or use `public $timestamps = false;` in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Because `create` only allows GET requests to show the form.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Add `'method' => 'post'` to your `Form::open()` array and point it at just `/questionnaires`.

Comment: My original answer was incorrect. There is a specific way you have to interact with the magic Resource controllers, including how you submit information. Read up on the documentation carefully; you must also specify an action as `'create'`.

Comment: really sorry for editing, clicked wrong answer. Rolled back.

Comment: No drama, I think your solution is more succinct regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you didn't setup any `POST` routes, that means that you cannot send a HTTP POST request to your Laravel site.

If you add this, it will be fine.

```
Route::post('/questionnaires/create', 'QuestionnairesController@create');
```

This will setup a route (HTTP POST request) to the `QuestionnairesController` with the function `create()`.

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks this worked! However, now that I have submitted the form I just get return back to the create.blade

Comment: You can set on the create function a return, the code will be: return redirect(url('/questionnaires'));

If the answer works for you, can you mark it as 'works'?

Comment: `create` using GET method. `store` uses POST. OP is using resource controllers, so he shouldn't add POST/create method manually. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: So what should I use? Because POST worked (as in, when I clicked submit, I didn't receive the error message again). However, I cannot see the questionnaire that I created on the /questionnaires page

Comment: You can use Jaw.sh, that's a standard Laravel function.

Comment: If you're using resource controllers, you should use them right. With them you'll get more readable and less redundant code. To understan what exactly `Route::resource` gives you, run `php artisan route:list` command and you will see 7 routes, automatically created for you. `Form::` will add right `_method` for each route and action.